# react native, installing cocoapods result: Folly can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

When attempting to install cocoapods in an existing react native project, I get the following error:

```
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
```

I'm not sure of the root cause. At first I thought it was a problem with `Apple Silicon (M1)`, but a colleague using an `x64` encountered the same problem.

Versions:

```
   "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.1",
```

I've combed through every related question I could find here. I haven't found one with a workable solution. Let me know if you need more info. Thanks.

Comment: I can't remember how I resolved this error and I'm not working for that client anymore. But I think it had something to do with upgrading to `RCT-Folly`. I would check on that if you arrived here looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

If Error -
`force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
[Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
Solution —
open Terminal and Navigate to your project location
sudo gem update xcodeproj
pod init